# Django 2.0.7. is missing the complete path in url when the user try to upload a file. It works on local enviroment but not in production server

Tags: django, image-uploading

I have a model with a ImageField:

```
class Usr( User ):
    idusuario = models.AutoField( primary_key = True )
    usuario = models.CharField( blank = False, unique = True, max_length = 50 )
    contraseña = models.CharField( blank = False, max_length = 250 )
    telefono = models.CharField( max_length = 15, blank = True, null = True )
    celular = models.CharField( max_length = 15, blank = True, null = True )
    fotografia = models.ImageField( blank = True, null = True, upload_to = 'usuarios' )
    depende_de = models.ForeignKey( 'self', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = '+', blank = True, null = True )
    def __unicode__( self ):
        return self.get_full_name()
    def __str__( self ):
        return self.get_full_name()
```

And its form (a ModelForm ):

```
class RegUsuario( forms.ModelForm ):
    class Meta:
        model = Usr
        fields = [ 
            'usuario', 
            'contraseña', 
            'is_active', 
            'is_superuser', 
            'first_name', 
            'last_name', 
            'email', 
            'telefono', 
            'celular', 
            'fotografia', 
            'groups', 
            'depende_de' 
        ]
```

In views (vw_usuario.py) I have:

```
@valida_acceso( [ 'usr.agregar_usuarios_usuario' ] )
def new( request ):
    if 'POST' == request.method:
        frm = RegUsuario( request.POST, files = request.FILES  )
        if frm.is_valid():
            obj = frm.save( commit = False )
            obj.username = obj.usuario
            obj.set_password( obj.contraseña )
            obj.save()
            for g in request.POST.getlist( 'groups' ):
                obj.groups.add( g )
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse( 'usuario_ver', kwargs = { 'pk' : obj.pk } ) )
    frm = RegUsuario( request.POST or None )
    return render( request, 'global/form.html', {
        'menu_main' : Usr.objects.filter( id = request.user.pk )[ 0 ].main_menu_struct(),
        'footer' : True,
        'titulo' : 'Usuarios',
        'titulo_descripcion' : 'Nuevo',
        'frm' : frm
    } )
```

And in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path( 'usuarios/nuevo/',            vw_usuario.new,     name = "usuario_nuevo" ),
    ...
    ]
```

If I go to http://example.com/usuarios/nuevo/ in the browser I can the form displayed as well, then I fill the fields and submit the form, and I got the exception:

```
Page not found (404) 
Request Method: POST 
Request URL:    http://example.com/usuarios/nuevo/ 
Raised by:  seguridad.mkitsafe.validacion 
Using the URLconf defined in example.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
... 
usuarios/eliminar/<pk>/ [name= usuario_eliminar ] 
usuarios/nuevo/ [name= usuario_nuevo ] 
usuarios/<pk>/ [name= usuario_ver ] 
... 
The current path, nuevo/, didn t match any of these.
```

I don't understand why the url is taken as `nuevo/` instead of `usuarios/nuevo/`

In the form template I'm setting `method = "post"`, `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `action=""` (I've also tried `action="usuarios/nuevo"` and `action="http://example.com/usuarios/nuevo/"`)

The path for `MEDIA_ROOT` exists and has enough perms.

The issue happens if I fill in the form the ImageField field or not.

I noticed that if I remove the field in the modelform, everything works as well.

The source code for seguridad.mkitsafe.validacion is:

```
def valida_acceso( permisos = None ):
    url_error = 'seguridad_inicio'
    url_autenticacion = 'seguridad_login'

    def _valida_acceso( vista ):

        def validacion( *args, **kwargs ):
            usuario = args[ 0 ].user
            if not usuario.is_authenticated:
                print_error( "Vista {} negada por autenticación".format( vista.__name__ ), "Exec Info" )
                return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse( url_autenticacion ) )
            if permisos is None:
                return vista( *args, **kwargs )
            perms = []
            for perm in permisos:
                permiso = Permiso.get_from_package_codename( perm )
                if( permiso is None ):
                    print_error( "No se ha encontrado el permiso: " + perm )
                else:
                    perms.append( permiso.perm() )
                    desc = permiso.descendencia()
                    for p in desc:
                        perms.append( p.perm() )
            for perm in perms:
                p = "{}.{}".format( perm.content_type.app_label, perm.codename )
                if usuario.has_perm( p ):
                    return vista( *args, **kwargs )
            print_error( "Vista {} negada por permisos {}".format( vista.__name__, permisos ), "Exec Info" )
            return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse( url_error ) )
        return validacion

    return _valida_acceso
```

And it is a decorator which verify perms and authentication.

If I remove this decorator the excepion changes in the `Raised by` to `seguridad.vw_usuario.new`

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://example.com/usuarios/nuevo/
Raised by:  seguridad.vw_usuario.new

Using the URLconf defined in example.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
...
usuarios/actualizar/<pk>/ [name='usuario_actualizar']
usuarios/eliminar/<pk>/ [name='usuario_eliminar']
usuarios/nuevo/ [name='usuario_nuevo']
usuarios/<pk>/ [name='usuario_ver']
usuarios/ [name='usuario_inicio']
...

The current path, nuevo/, didn't match any of these.
```

I also noticed that when the error is raised and the decorator is active the decorator or the view function is not called.

I also tried to copy a file in MEDIA_ROOT path with an script and it worked as well, so the script has right access to this path.

Any comment about the issue?

Comment: Please show the view `seguridad.mkitsafe.validacion` referenced in the traceback.

Comment: Sure Alasdair, It is the Updates, at the end of the question's description

Comment: In the first error the urls tried are from `example.urls`, and in the second `tocatres.urls`. Sure the problem is not the urls configuration?

Comment: The real name of the project is tocatres, so the url file is tocatres.urls.py, I changed it for this forum

Comment: Please show the entire `new` view. Is there a traceback in the error message which you are not showing?

Comment: @Alasdair I updated the `new` view, just adding the decorator :-)

There's no more in the traceback. I just hide some elements in the path / url list.

Comment: You are still showing `...` instead of the `new` view.

Comment: In vw_usuario.py , you can see the complete function

Comment: same issue twice: `nuevo/` is not in your urls.py

Comment: @gregory But I'm not looking for `nuevo/`, in the form `action='http://example.com/usuarios/nuevo/'` (I also try `action='usuarios/nuevo/'` and `action=''` ) django is looking just for `nuevo/`, but happens just when request.method is POST, and it just happen when in the ModelForm I set `fotografia` field (which is a ImageField, I mean if I remove this field from the ModelForm everything works as well.

Comment: @RubenRG, is the pk missing? inspect the line: "return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse( 'usuario_ver', kwargs = { 'pk' : obj.pk } )"

Comment: @gregory I don't think so, when the exception is fired it happens before to call the view function, and also before to call its decorator.